# Run an Access 2010 macro by using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: ms-access

How can I create Ctrl+Shift+Q shortkey to run a macro in Access 2010? I found how to do it but only for 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new macro. Before you do anything, open the Action Catalog and double-click the Submacro option.  Give the submacro a name to match the key you want.  For example ^+Q for your case. Assign to Action desired value. Save the macro with `AutoKeys` name and restart the application.

Comment: For what it's worth, `^+Q` did not work for me in Access 2016. But `^Q` did work.